# SQL Script throws PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Here is the code I am using for the problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DIS_CUSTOMER( I_CUSTOMER_NUM IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM%TYPE) AS
I_CUSTOMER_NAME    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME%TYPE;
I_CREDIT_LIMIT     CUSTOMER.CREDIT_LIMIT%TYPE;

BEGIN
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, CREDIT_LIMIT
INTO I_CUSTOMER_NAME, I_CUSTOMER_LIMIT
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM = I_CUSTOMER_NUM;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE((I_CUSTOMER_NAME)||' '||(I_CREDIT_LIMIT));
END;
/​
```

The error I am receiving is "Error at line 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" but I can't figure out why it is ignoring it. I know it is probably something so simple though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just needed to post it online to see my mistake.
In line 7 I_CUSTOMER_LIMIT should actually be I_CREDIT_LIMIT.